# ¿como tener internet usando maquina virtual en VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualización

Mi computadora no corre el internet cuando uso maquina virtual con VirtualBox. Actualmente estoy utilizando Windows 7 con una red WIFI.
¿Tienen idea de porque podrá ser?

Comment: Podrás aclarar un poco más tu problema? Sistema operativo, programa, red lan o wifi, etc.

Comment: sistema operativo windows 7 programa virtual box red de wifi es del izzi xD

Comment: ¿qué es el izzi?

Comment: por lo general virtual box me genera problemas con las conexiones wifi te recomiendo conectar un cable y hacer las configuaciones en network dentro de virtual box.

Comment: @Shaz izzi es un mercado que ofrece servicios de telecomunicaciones, en este caso es la compañía que le ofrece internet.

Comment: Es importante revises [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y esta sea de ayuda no solo a tí si no a la comunidad. @Yaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible que tengas deshabilitado el adaptador de internet. Fijate en la imagen que te dejo a continuación.

[image: Virtual box]

Comment: no entiendo porque me quieren cerrar la cuenta si solo pregunte dos dias seguidos algo no muy complicado y recibo muchos dislikes de las personas eso esta mal algun consejo?

Comment: Porque las preguntas las hacés muy amplias y falta información. La próxima vez informa más al respecto de tu problema, si es posible, edita cuando sea conveniente e intenta agregar esas cosas que se te ponen en los comentarios.

Comment: Yaz puedes informarte en [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tambien cualquier duda que tengas puedes visitar [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) que se ubica al final de la pagina(en el footer). saludos

Comment: @Yaz otro motivo por el cual posiblemente recibiste puntos negativos en un principio fue porque colocaste tu pregunta con las etiquetas de "javascript, html, jquery y css", gente con intención de ayudar espera ver preguntas relacionadas con dichas etiquetas.